Can not get my SQL Select statement to work with CASE
SQL Noob here. Pulling some data from a custom table in a WP install and I want to get the user information from both user_meta and users table.
The resulting array should look like this.
array(
 user_id => 1234,
 user_email => mail@mail.com
 first_name => foo
 last_name => bar
)

I just cant get my CASE statement right.
$query = $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT s.user_id, u.user_email         
    FROM wp_user_stages s 
    INNER JOIN wp_users u ON s.user_id=u.ID 
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta m ON s.user_id=m.user_id
    CASE 
        WHEN m.met_key = 'first_name' THEN m.meta_value AS first_name
        WHEN m.met_key = 'last_name' THEN m.meta_value AS last_name
    END
    WHERE 
        s.quest_comp = 0 AND
        s.registered = %s           
    ",
    '2024-05-11'    
    );
$users = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);

I've looked at various manuals and tried the case statement in different formats and different places. I've used it before but so long ago I just cant remember.

What happens instead when running that query? Are you sure this problem is directly related to Wordpress? What would happen when you run the same query directly, for example using MySQL Workbench, phpMyAdmin, or MySQL's shell?

@NicoHaase same error.

You need to aggregate by user and then use pivoting logic to extract the key values:
SELECT
    s.user_id,
    u.user_email,
    MAX(CASE WHEN m.met_key = 'first_name' THEN m.meta_value END) AS first_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN m.met_key = 'last_name' THEN m.meta_value END) AS last_name       
FROM wp_user_stages s 
INNER JOIN wp_users u ON s.user_id = u.ID 
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta m ON s.user_id = m.user_id
WHERE 
    s.quest_comp = 0 AND
    s.registered = %s
GROUP BY
    s.user_id,
    u.user_email       


Change your sql script as:
SELECT s.user_id, u.user_email,
    CASE 
        WHEN m.met_key = 'first_name' THEN m.meta_value
        ELSE ''
    END  AS first_name,
    CASE 
        WHEN m.met_key = 'last_name' THEN m.meta_value
        ELSE ''
    END  AS last_name      
    FROM wp_user_stages s 
    INNER JOIN wp_users u ON s.user_id=u.ID 
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta m ON s.user_id=m.user_id
    WHERE 
        s.quest_comp = 0 AND
        s.registered = %s 

